# Populate Drop Down from Database PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I see that this has been asked a few times, but following all the other threads has gotten me nowhere. I am trying to populate a drop-down from a database, but I keep getting a blank drop down.. I swear it must be because a simple mistake I am making.

```
<select name="Verb List">
        <?php fillVerblist($dbc); ?>
</select>

<?php
function fillVerblist($dbc) {

mysqli_query($dbc, 'SET NAMES UTF8');

$sql = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM verblist WHERE form = 'F'"); 


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

    echo' <option value="verblist">'.$row['specificColumn'].'</option>';
}
}

?>
```

thanks!

Comment: You can easily debug that by looking at the resulting HTML. Either the HTML will be wrong, or there will be no options (which means your query/data is wrong). Figuring that out will help you debug.

Comment: is the value supposed to be the same on every option?

Comment: they wont be the same.. I want to pull all that match form=F, which is a lot of rows, but the 'specificColumn' is different for every row.

Comment: `<option value="verblist">` will be the same for every iteration in recordset

Comment: so do I just leave it blank?

Comment: Dont forget the i after mysql, `mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)`

Comment: thanks Jay!  that did give me a blank drop down, but at least it appears to have been made as long as the number of results it returned.. so that's progress, but it's still blank.

Comment: No, do not leave it blank. What value should it hold? Generally I would say it would be the ID for the record but there is no necessity that is the case

Comment: @RamRaider if the value attribute is omitted, the value will be taken from the text content.

Comment: @scott.schaffer if you are going to use the same thing you're displaying as the value, you can just remove the value attribute. If you want something different to be used as the value, such as a row id, you can specify that. But  setting it to a constant like verblist means every option will have the same value, regardless of the text content.

Comment: @Don't Panic, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php): `mysql_fetch_assoc()` was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, so use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`

If you want each option value to match the text displayed, then do:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   echo' <option value="'.$row['specificColumn'].'">'.$row['specificColumn'].'</option>';
}
```

As DontPanic stated in comments, you can also omit the value attribute and the text will be used as the value.

To debug the blank select further throw this inside the while loop:

```
echo '<pre>';
echo $row;
echo '</pre>';
```

That will tell you what is being returned from your database and if your data/query is incorrect.

Comment: hot damn! it worked! so I can use this as a learning experience instead of being spoon-fed, could you explain what I did wrong? side note: I think you left out some apostrophes in the 'option value' area to separate the php.

Comment: =) Gladly, if I knew exactly haha. I think it was just the missing i in mysqli. Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php And notice the big red Warning that it was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0...so you didn't need the debug lines?

Comment: Thanks, edited the single quotes (apostrophes). I edited the value so that the value was the same as the output, but that shouldn't have been an error, since a select can have multiple options with the same value. The only error was the missing i.

Answer (score 1):

Took a little while to write but a simple class like the following would simplify the whole creation of select menus - just feed in different parameters and out pops a different menu. The most common usage of `DOMDocument` tends to be in parsing a document - be that XML or HTML but it's methods are perfectly suited to generating content on the fly - in this instance a simple select menu that is technically correct within the DOM.

```
<?php

    class selectmenu{
        private $dbo;
        private $name;
        private $sql;

        public function __construct( $dbo, $name, $sql ){
            $this->dbo=$dbo;
            $this->name=$name;
            $this->sql=$sql;
        }

        public function create(){
            $result=$this->dbo->query( $this->sql );
            if( $result ){

                $dom=new DOMDocument;

                $select=$dom->createElement('select');
                $dom->appendChild( $select );
                $attr=$dom->createAttribute( 'name' );
                $attr->value=$this->name;
                $select->appendChild( $attr );


                while( $rs = $result->fetch_object() ){
                    /*
                        The option value is the ID and the innerHTML is
                        whatever column name is designated as `value` in the 
                        query. The names of these are fairly arbitary - you
                        could call them anything really in the query but change
                        the field here( ie: $rs->value to $rs->somecolumn )
                    */
                    $option=$dom->createElement('option');
                    $option->nodeValue=$rs->value;

                    $attr=$dom->createAttribute( 'value' );
                    $attr->value=$rs->id;

                    $option->appendChild( $attr );
                    $select->appendChild( $option );
                }
                return $dom->saveHTML();
            }
            return 'error';
        }
    }
```

And to use the class you would do something like this.

```
    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'xxx';
    $db=new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );

    /* the column `Name` is aliased as `value` */
    $sql_city="select `id`, `Name` as 'value' from `city` limit 20;";
    $name_city='city';

    /* note column aliases !! */
    $sql_country="select `code` as 'id', `Region` as 'value' from `country` limit 20;";
    $name_country='country';



    $obj=new selectmenu( $db, $name_city, $sql_city );
    $city=$obj->create();

    $obj=new selectmenu( $db, $name_country, $sql_country );
    $country=$obj->create();


    echo $city, $country;

?>
```

The same idea could be done with PDO but the methods would need to be changed appropriately.

More specifically for the original question

```
$sql="SELECT `col` as 'id', `othercol` as 'value' FROM verblist WHERE form = 'F'";
$name='verblist';

$obj=new selectmenu( $dbc, $name, $sql );
$menu=$obj->create();
echo $menu;
```